# Raspberry Pi B/ model programming UART

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, libraries, uart, rxtx

I have a [Vex ARM Cortex-based Microcontroller](http://www.vexrobotics.com/276-2194.html) and a [Raspberry Pi B model](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/model-b/), so I had the idea of having the Microcontroller send information through the UART Ports to the Pi. I have everything working on the Microcontroller's end since can easily test that it reads and writes to itself, but my trouble comes in when I try to program the Pi. I am using Java to write the program and I am also using the Java rxtx library. After I got a simple program that would test the ability to send and receive things I tried to run it and got the `UnsatisfiedLinkErorr: no rxtxSerial in Java.library.path`which I fixed by going in and editing the native library location to the one for mac, as I am writing this on a mac. I then run it on my mac and it gets to the point of it seeing that the tty that I gave it was used or something along those lines, which is good since that means everything ran correctly. However, when I go to Pi it does not work and I get the same error `UnsatisfiedLinkErorr: no rxtxSerial in Java.library.path`, so I think that it is the native library location not being for linux, but I do not know which machine type I should use since there are three to choose from, if that is even the problem.

Comment: Isn't this just a case of forgetting to include the rxtx library in the output jar? It says it can't find the library, which sounds logical, cause it's not a default Java library.

Comment: I added the library through eclipse and checked off on exporting with the libraries in the jar file. When I did not do this I got an error of it not being able to find gnu.io so i do not think that is the issue